# Sendy installation on Heroku with mysqli extension

Tags: heroku, mysqli

I am using this tutorial https://gist.github.com/danielepolencic/6983030 to install mysqli on Heroku. However, when I check http://sendy-apps.herokuapp.com/_compatibility.php?i=1, I get 'mysqli extension is not installed.'

I have checked all common errors, including .htaccess and double-checked everything in config.php. Any other ideas why this might be happening?

Also, I tried to log in to the database via Sequel Pro using the login details generated by the ClearDB extension in Heroku. However, it does not work.

Comment: I was having the same issue, the gist you posted seems to work for me though.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. I updated that Gist.

https://gist.github.com/dovy/3a82773ffc73b2c725d7